# Is every punishment Mida K'neged Mida?

Tags: reward-punishment

Is every single punishment given in the form of Mida K'neged Mida ("Measure for Measure" - i.e. the punishment is in the same vein as the transgression) or just in some special cases?

Answer (score 1):

sometimes no. Job's suffering was chosen for other reasons as the shaar bitachon says ch.3

> To demonstrate his good bearing and good acceptance of suffering in
>   the service of G-d, so that others will learn from him, as you know
>   from the matter of Job.

Comment: How do you know that besides for achieving those results it wasn't also _midda k'negged midda_?

Comment: @mevaqesh like what?

Comment: Suffering does not equal punishment.